# What happens if the father wants the money, rather than his son?

Tags: kohen-priest, pidyon-haben, priestly-gifts-matanot-kehunah

I think I'm already getting into the spirit of Purim Torah, but this question is completely serious: i

If the father of a bechor [firstborn son] wishes to keep his five sela'im of silver, rather than his child, what would happen ?

I'm not wondering about what would happen in the Temple Period, but after, both historically and in the current day.

Comment: Why do we need a new tag for priestly gifts? Is Pidyon Haben not sufficient?

Comment: @DoubleAA, the question revolves around the bechor being the gift, rather than being redeemed w/ kessef

Comment: So why does that mean we need another tag?

Comment: It's a more general tag, which also works with the choice bits of beheimot, bechorot, terumot, ma'aserot, et c, considering that this is one of only 24 of them. I actually looked for a tag before creating it, since I think it's a useful one to have

Comment: Why do we need a tag that works for all 24? Is the tag for each not sufficient? You're just describing it, not explaining why it is useful. We could lots of generalized categories as tags but we don't because it's not helpful

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think a general tag is also relevant, even if it is not always applicable due to the existence of a prat. In this case, I did not think that the specific tag of [pidyon-haben] was sufficient, so I added the new tag, since I didn't know which other specific tags would work, I created a general one which applied.

Comment: Why is the pidyon haben tag insufficient? Is it not the most obvious category to look in to find this question? Would you not expect this to be dealt with always in the Hilkhot Pidyon Haben section of any Halakhic compendium? In what way is this not about the laws of the Mitzva of Pidyon Haben?